# how to fix this code so that it can test the integers present next to the character?

Tags: c, string, sum, alphanumeric

Given a string containing alphanumeric characters, calculate the sum of all numbers present in the string.
The problem with my code is that it displays the integers present before the characters, but it is not summing up the integers after the characters.

The execution is easy in python and C++ but I cant get it done using C! Can anyone please verify where I have done wrong? << thank you !

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int convert(char[]);
int main()
{
    char ch[100],temp[100]={0};
    int i=0,s=0,j=0,n;
    scanf("%s",ch);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(ch);i++)
    {  
        if((ch[i]>='0') && (ch[i]<='9'))
        {
            temp[j]=ch[i]; 
            j++;
        }
        else
        {   
            if(temp[0]== '\0')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else 
            {
                n=convert(temp);
                s+=n;
                temp[0]= '\0';
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",s);
    return 0;
}
int convert(char s[]) //converting string to integer
{
    int n=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        n= n * 10 + s[i] - '0'; 
    }
return n;
}
```

Input :           12abcd4 
 
Expected output : 16

But the output is 12 for my code.

Comment: `temp[0]= '\0';` does not empty or clear the entire `temp` array. It only sets the first byte to `\0`, making it superficially look like an empty string. As soon as you put a new character into `temp[0]`, you 'll immediately have a string staring with that character, and continuing with whatever was in the rest of `temp` beforehand. use a `memset` to clear `temp` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. The first was mentioned in the comments : if the last character is a digit, the last "number section" will not be taken into account. But I don't think that the solution given in the comments is good because if the last character is not a digit, you will have a wrong value. To correct this, I added an if statement that check if the last character is a digit, if so call convert().

The second problem is that strlen return the number of characters in you string from the beginning until it finds an '\0'. The way you used your string lead to the follow problem :
ch = "12abcd4". 
At first you have temp = '1' + '2' + '\0'... 
After calling convert() you set temp[0] to '\0', thus temp = '\0' + '2' + '\0'... . 
And when you start reading digit again, you set '4' in temp[0]. Your string is now : '4' + '2' + '\0'... . 
The n returned will be 42 and your result 54 (12+42). There are several solution to have the expected behavior, I chose to use your variable j to indicate how many characters should be read instead of using strlen() :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int convert(char[], int size);

int main() {
  char ch[100],temp[100]={0};
  int i=0,s=0,j=0,n;
  scanf("%s",ch);
  for(i=0;i<strlen(ch);i++) {
    if((ch[i]>='0') && (ch[i]<='9')) {
      temp[j]=ch[i]; 
      j++;

      // change here
      if(i == strlen(ch) - 1) {
        n=convert(temp, j);
        s+=n;
      }
    }
    else {
      // change here
      n=convert(temp, j);
      s+=n;

      if(temp[0]== '\0') {
    continue;
      }

      temp[0]= '\0';
      j=0;
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n",s);
  return 0;
}

//change here
int convert(char s[], int size) {
  int n=0;
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    n= n * 10 + s[i] - '0';
  }
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of [`strtoul()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) and [`strpbrk()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk) to do this.

Declare two character pointers `start_ptr` and `end_ptr` and make `start_ptr` point to the beginning of the string under consideration.

```
char *start_ptr=s, *end_ptr;
```

where `s` is the character array of size 100 holding the string.

Since your string has only alphanumeric characters, there is no `-` sign and hence there are no negative numbers. So we can get away with using unsigned integers.

We are using `strtoul()` from `stdlib.h` to perform the string to integer conversion. So let's declare two variables: `rv` for holding the value returned by `strtoul()` and `sum` to hold the sum of numbers.

```
unsigned long rv, sum_val=0;
```

Now use a loop:

```
for(; start_ptr!=NULL; )
{
    rv = strtoul(start_ptr, &end_ptr, 10);
    if(rv==ULONG_MAX && errno==ERANGE)
    {
        //out of range!
        printf("\nOut of range.");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%lu", rv);
        sum_val += rv;
        start_ptr=strpbrk(end_ptr, "0123456789");
    }
}
```

`strtoul()` will convert as much part of the string as possible and then make `end_ptr` point to the first character of the part of the string that could not be converted.

It will return `ULONG_MAX` if the number is too big and [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) would be set to `ERANGE`.

Otherwise the converted number is returned.

`strpbrk()` would search for a set of characters (in this case the characters 0-9) and return a pointer to the first match. Otherwise `NULL` is returned.

Don't forget to include the following header files:

```
stdlib.h ---> strtoul
string.h ---> strpbrk
limits.h ---> ULONG_MAX
errno.h  ---> errno
```

In short, we could make the program to something like

```
for(; start_ptr!=NULL; sum_val += rv, start_ptr=strpbrk(end_ptr, "0123456789"))
{
    rv = strtoul(start_ptr, &end_ptr, 10);
    if(rv==ULONG_MAX && errno==ERANGE)
    {
        //out of range!
        break;
    }
}
printf("\n\n%lu", sum_val);
```

So the value of `sum_val` for the string "12abcd4" would be `16`.

---

`scanf()` is usually not the best way to accept input that is not well-formatted. Maybe you can use `fgets()`-`sscanf()` combo instead.

If you must use `scanf()`, make sure that you check the value returned by it, which in your case must be `1` (the number of successful assignments that `scanf()` made).

And to prevent overflow, use a width specifier as in

```
scanf("%99s",ch);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s",ch);
```

as `100` is the size of the `ch` character array and we need one extra byte to store the string delimiter (the `\0` character).